# Set filedirectory in LaTex individually for each data type(csvsimple)

Tags: csv, csvsimple, variable, directory

I am new to LaTex coding; so if this question has already been asked just let me know and post the link :)
I try to  put a lot of small csv tables into a LaTeX file and found this solution online (which is in my opinion very clever).
https://kawahara.ca/latex-how-to-programmatically-change-the-path-of-your-figures/

I could't get it to work; I am also open for other solutions. I want the csv files in another folder and want to set the directory for figures as well somewhere else to have a overview where I find all the data(hence I don't want to set an overall working directory where I put everything.)

```
\documentclass[margin=10mm]{article} %margins are 10mm to use the whole page for images, also doesnt work..
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{csvsimple}


\def\bloep{\D:\Dokumente\Masterthesis\csvfiles}
%\usepackage{varwidth}
%\graphicspath{{:D\}{Dokumente\}{Masterthesis\}{LaTex-Dokumente\}{lateximages\}}  % this here also doesnt work so I gave it up
\begin{document}
\csvautotabular{\bloep tryone.csv}{\csv\seperator=;}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Don Hosek thanks, that worked for the auxfile.
I also created the error message: Package pdftex.def Error which might be connected to a wrong directory. With the code line:

```
\def\bloep{D:/Dokumente/Masterthesis/csvfiles/}
```

And a slash behind the last folder name, everything works properly.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. First, you can't use backslashes the way you have because LaTeX will assume you mean macros. You would use forward slashes instead (I think also that you don't need the slash before the drive letter). Also, you need a slash at the end of the path to separate it from the file name so this should work:

```
\def\bloep{D:/Dokumente/Masterthesis/csvfiles}
```

I'm not on Windows so I can't verify.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Unfortunately, I now created a "Undefined control sequence" error in the aux file when there wasn't one before. I also could't include the image(tried it with an image in the same folder csvfiles) and got  a big white box that says in the middle :
D:/Dokumente/Masterthesis/csvfilesarcanine.png instead of the picture :/

Comment: @Syralia Try deleting your .aux file and re-running.